# manage account mvc app c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to get my ‘manage’ link to redirect to the relevant account.
I have a BankAccsController which works for fine for viewing details for a logged in user and to see both accounts held in the database, but what I want to do is be able to click the corresponding button to the right of the account and for it to take me to the details for that specific account. I know I will have to create a new method to replace the current two ‘ViewCurrent and ViewSavings’ and use parameters but I’m unsure how to do it and can’t find the correct words to type it into Google.

[image: ePic of my accounts page]

**Controller**

```
//View all accounts of logged in user
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var bankAccs = db.BankAccs.Where(a => a.AccUserId == userId).ToList();
        return View(bankAccs.ToList());
    }

    ////View current account  of logged in user
    public ActionResult ViewCurrent()
    {

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ViewModels.CurrentAccVm bankVm = new ViewModels.CurrentAccVm();
        bankVm.BankAccList = db.BankAccs.Where(a => a.AccUserId == userId && a.AccTypeId == 1).ToList();
        bankVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        return View(bankVm);
    }

    ////View Savings account  of logged in user
    public ActionResult ViewSavings()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ViewModels.CurrentAccVm bankVm = new ViewModels.CurrentAccVm();
        bankVm.BankAccList = db.BankAccs.Where(a => a.AccUserId == userId && a.AccTypeId == 2).ToList();
        bankVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        return View(bankVm);
    }
```

**View**

```
     @model IEnumerable<Atm11.Models.BankAcc>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Balance)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccType.AccountType)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Balance)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccType.AccountType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Manage", "ViewAccounts", new { id = item.Id })

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You have a link which directs to an action called `ViewAccounts`.  Have you created that action?  What's stopping you from creating it?

Comment: I haven’t created one, no. That is the part I’m unsure of. I don’t know how to write the method and the correct syntax for passing the parameters correctly. Cheers

Comment: Then honestly it sounds like what you’re looking for are some introductory tutorials on ASP.NET MVC.  Creating an action method is generally covered there.  As a hint: Your new method would be called “ViewAccounts”, would have a parameter called “id”, and would return an “ActionResult”.

Comment: Ok thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close!  Add the below method to your controller.  Your view is constructed correctly so no changes are needed to that file.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ViewAccounts(int id)
{

    var myAccount = DB.Accounts.GetByID(id);
    return View(myAccount);
}
```

Next, you will need to create a ViewAccounts view.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I’ll give it a go.

Comment: @robbiedarza please mark this answer as accepted.  This is the answer to the question that you asked.  For future expansion of this question, please create a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much sorted now.